# How to print a report list of all the buyers and their purchases

Tags: c#

I am trying to print a list of all of the buyers and what they bought from the shop.
The list only shows one buyer and the item he bought as the first list item and all of the other items that other buyers bought, but it won't show who bought the other items:

[image: Main page]

I can only check who bought the other items if i enter the exact date when the item was bought in both fields of the date:

[image: Sorted out page]

This is the code for grouping:

```
var query =
            $@"SELECT
                bask.id,
                bask.buy_date,
                buy.name,
                buy.lastname,
                prod.name,
                bask.amount,
                bask.price,
                bask.sum,
                bs1.total_amount
            FROM
                `basket` bask
                INNER JOIN `buyer` buy ON buy.buyer_id = 
                bask.fk_buyer
                LEFT JOIN `product` prod ON prod.prod_code = 
                bask.fk_name
                LEFT JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT
                            buy1.buyer_id,
                            sum(bask1.sum) as total_amount
                        FROM `basket` bask1, `buyer` buy1
                        WHERE
                            buy1.buyer_id=bask1.fk_buyer
                            AND bask1.buy_date >= IFNULL(?from, 
                            bask1.buy_date)
                            AND bask1.buy_date <= IFNULL(?to, 
                            bask1.buy_date)
                            GROUP BY buy1.buyer_id
                    ) AS bs1
                    ON bs1.buyer_id = buy.buyer_id
            WHERE
                bask.buy_date >= IFNULL(?from, bask.buy_date)
                AND bask.buy_date <= IFNULL(?to, bask.buy_date)
            GROUP BY 
                bask.id, buy.buyer_id
            ORDER BY 
                buy.lastname ASC";
```

This is the code to print buyers name and total price of the items bought:

```
@if( Model.PirktosPrekes.Count == 0 )
        @for( int i = 0; i < Model.PirktosPrekes.Count; i++ )
        {
            if( i == 0 || Model.PirktosPrekes[i].PirkejoId != Model.PirktosPrekes[i- 
            1].PirkejoId )
            {
            <tr style="background-color: lightblue">
                <td colspan="5" align="center"><b>@Html.DisplayFor(m => 
  Model.PirktosPrekes[i].Vardas) @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.PirktosPrekes[i].Pavarde) 
  </b></td>
            </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td>#@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.PirktosPrekes[i].Nr)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.PirktosPrekes[i].PirkimoData)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.PirktosPrekes[i].Pavadinimas)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.PirktosPrekes[i].Kiekis)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.PirktosPrekes[i].Kaina)</td>
            </tr>
            if( i == Model.PirktosPrekes.Count-1 || Model.PirktosPrekes[i].PirkejoId != 
Model.PirktosPrekes[i + 1].PirkejoId )
            {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
                <td><b>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.PirktosPrekes[i].BendraSuma)</b></td>
            </tr>
            }
```

What did i do here wrong? Maybe it's the grouping of database tables wrong or wrong if statements to print the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change [ != ] to [ == ] to print all buyers:

```
if( i == 0 || Model.PirktosPrekes[i].PirkejoId **==** Model.PirktosPrekes[i- 1].PirkejoId )
```

and to print the sum of each buyer from [ != ] to [ == ], the value of an item times price of an item:

```
if( i == Model.PirktosPrekes.Count-1 || Model.PirktosPrekes[i].PirkejoId **==** Model.PirktosPrekes[i + 1].PirkejoId )
```